# Migrate before I run the code Laravel 8 migrations

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to replace my .env with a query to database getting the same path and value as I have in env, but I got a problem in Laravel 8.

When I try to run `php artisan migrate --seed` it doesn't recognize my table because it's not migrated, so I want to know if there's a way to migrate this table BEFORE everything in my code?

The Error:

```
      PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'superlaravel.configurations' doesn't exist")
\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:692
    688▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    689▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    690▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    691▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 692▕             throw new QueryException(
    693▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    694▕             );
    695▕         }

  • A table was not found: You might have forgotten to run your migrations. You can run your migrations using `php artisan migrate`.
    https://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations#running-migrations
```

Query:

```
class Helper {
    public static function getConfigValue(string $path) {
        $config = DB::table('configurations')->where('path', $path)->first();
        if ($config == null) return '';
        
        return $config->value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `php artisan migrate` and then `php artisan db:seed`?

Comment: Yup! The problem is since I made a query to get the path's value in my code, I guess Laravel is reading the code and throw the error so it can't migrate the table.

Comment: You can't query to the database to get anything until there is no table, or if you still need to do something before migration goes, add those DB::statement in AppServiceProvider.